# How to fix "jsonPath is not defined" error in WSO2 EI (v6.4.0)

Tags: javascript, json, wso2, jsonpath, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have some .js files in my project which I develop them in WSO2 EI v6.4.0 and I want to use jsonPath in a function which is in a `template.js` file but I receive an error in console which is `jsonPath is not defined.` How can I import jsonPath library into WSO2 v6.4.0?

- I have already added json-path-2.4.0.jar file into wso2home/lib and wso2home/dropins files.
- I have already added groovy-all-2.4.4 into wso2home/lib and wso2home/dropins files.
- I tried to import `import groovy.json.*`,  `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`,  `import com.jayway.jsonpath` libraries in `.js` file but it didn't work.

```
function denemeJsonPath(){
    var newPayload = {"store":{"book":[{"searchTerm":"AA","country":"BB","language":"CC"},{"searchTerm":"DD","country":"EE","language":"FF"},{"searchTerm":"GG","country":"HH","language":"ZZ"}]}};
    var response = jsonPath(newPayload , "$..book[2]").toJSONString();
    print ("responseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee:"+response);
}
```

It prints following error on console:

`org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "jsonPath" is not defined.`

I expect to use jsonPath function in my sequence and template files in WSO2 v6.4.0

Comment: did you find any solutions to this problem?